# Acces viewController's properties from the TabBarController

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` (embedded in a `UINavigationController`) which have some "child" `UIViewControllers`.

When the user arrives on the TabBarController, the first ViewController is shown. I'm handling the datas in my TabBarController, and then I'm using it in the different viewControllers. So it's not a problem to access the TabBarController's properties from the children ViewControllers.

Now, what I'm trying to do is to access the children ViewControllers' properties, inside my TabBarController.

I know that something like this is possible to loop through the controllers :

```
for (UIViewController *v in self.viewControllers)
{
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]])
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

This code works, I correctly find `MyViewController`, but now I don't know how to access its properties. Could someone give me a tip on how do this please ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (UIViewController *v in self.viewControllers)
{
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]])
    {
       MyViewController *myViewControllerObj = (MyViewController *)v;

        // you can access all the properies here
        // example: myViewControllerObj.yourPropery;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I tried first but this seems to don't work. When I try to NSLog a UILabel's text, it show me `(null)`.

Comment: What exactly is (null)? The UILabel or its text property? 
If null is shown then it is probabyl really null at that point in time.

Comment: u may creating an new object for MyViewController after assigned value to UILabel. It may be in UITabBarController or any where else. please cross check the  MyViewController allocations. Else it will work fine. also cross check the myViewControllerObj object values. it will give good idea to u

Answer (score 0):

cast tye to your secific ViewController and access properties. Dont foget to include your header file in .m file.

Header:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
```

type casting:

```
MyViewController *vc = (MyViewController*) v;
v.myProperty = myValue;
```